# Postgres vs EF 6 Unique with NULL Value

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-6, unique

I need to create this index bellow:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MYINDEX" ON myTable USING btree (field1, filed2, (field3 IS NULL));
```

Only field3 can be null, but I cannot allow user add another row with field3 NULL when all the others two fields are equal. This index above is working as expected.

But I don`t know how to do that in Entity Framework 6 using CodeFirst.

My actual index is like that in EF:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
     .HasIndex(t => new { t.Field1, t.Field2, t.Field3})
     .IsUnique();
```

But, this will generate a wrong index for me.

Thanks in advance.